# Вывод нескольких Яндекс Карт на разных языках на одной странице

Tags: yandex-maps-api

По [документации](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/dg/concepts/localization-docpage/) имеем, что язык карты задается при подключении их JS на страница при помощи параметра `lang`.

```
<script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?apikey=<ваш API-ключ>&lang=en_US" type="text/javascript">
```

Как быть, если мне нужно изменить динамически язык карты после инициализации карты и как вывести две карты на разных яыках на одной странице?

Answer (score 0):

Пример динамического изменения языка карты есть в песочнице: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/language

> как вывести две карты на разных языках на одной странице

Насколько я знаю, карты с разными региональными настройками нельзя вывести за один вызов API. Вторую карту можно получить, например, через Конструктор https://yandex.ru/map-constructor/

Comment: Смысл писать ответ, если оно не решает задачу)